# How to query from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been doing a lot of searching and I cannot figure out how to do a simple query from firebase. Here is the structure of my db:

[image: Database]

The parent of "locations" is the name of the database. I am trying to just get a List of all the children of "locations" Here is what is not working for me:

```
 mFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Create location list
    mFirebase.child("locations").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot entry: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("HERE: ", entry.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The Log.d method is never ran, so it is never entering the forEach loop. Is there an easier way to query from the database, or am I doing this wrong? Thanks

EDIT: Changed to addListenerForSingleValueEvent() and added a line before the ForEach loop to be sure that the onDataChange() method is actually being called (which it is)

```
mFirebase.child("locations").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("Entered: ", "onDataChange");
            for(DataSnapshot entry: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("HERE: ", entry.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is the entire code: (Note: I am switching from SQLite to firebase, so there is still code from SQLite there, that will be gone when I get Firebase working.

```
package osu.mobile_apps.ohiostatetourchallenge;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import database.OsuTourDbSchema.DatabaseHelper;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mlocations;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;
private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
private DatabaseReference mFirebase;

// Stops the back button
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TESTING","ON CREATE() FOR LIST");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    //Get username from log in activity
    //String userName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("User");

    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    if(welcome != null) {
        //welcome.setText("Welcome " + userName + "!");
    }
    mlocations = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.locationList);
    //Every item has fixed size
    mlocations.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Create location list
    mFirebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("Before Loop: ", dataSnapshot.toString());
            for(DataSnapshot entry: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("HERE: ", entry.getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    mlocations.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    List<Location> locations = mDatabaseHelper.getLocations();
    Collections.sort(locations, Location.LocationNameComparator);
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    String description;
    String smallDescription;

    for(Location entry: locations) {
        description = entry.getDescription();
        //TODO Check if location is unlocked or not
        if (description.length()>110){
            smallDescription = description.substring(0,110) + "...";
        } else {
            smallDescription = description;
        }
        ListItem item = new ListItem(entry.getName(), smallDescription);
        listItems.add(item);
    }

    mAdapter = new myAdpater(listItems);

    mlocations.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.map:
            //Start map activity

            return true;

        case R.id.about:
            //Start about activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, InformationActivity.class);
    if(v.getId()==R.id.textViewHead){
        TextView TestView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
        intent.putExtra("Header", TestView.getText());
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the code is correct, but its not working since you need to change the rules in the firebase console.

So go to firebase database then click on rules and change the rules to this:

```
{
"rules": {
   ".read": "true",
   ".write": "true"
 }
}
```

You will get this output in the log:-

```
D/HERE:: DataSnapshot { key = 1, value = {description=sadasd, latitude=dssdfds} }

D/HERE:: DataSnapshot { key = 2, value = {description=asdasdas, latitude=randomwords} }
```

**Edit for future viewers**

After Frank van Puffelen comment the problem was from the quotations, in the key nodes

[image: sample]

Comment: Hi Peter. I have the rules set up in the Firebase console the same way, but loop is still never entered.

Comment: I tested it and that was the problem, add a breakpoint next to the loop and then debug the app and see what you get.

Comment: It is entering the method. However I am having some issues with the debugger at the moment, I'll get back to you when I get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Peter. So, I went through the debugger and the method is not entered until after the activity layout is created and everything (new to android development so let me know if I need to be more clear on some things). Once the layout is rendered to the screen, then it goes into the onDataChange method. It also give me this message at the breakpoint: dataSnapshot: "DataSnapshot { key = locations, value = null }" It also looks like it's saying that the dataSnapshot for "locations" does not have any children.

Comment: yes 'value=null` means that you are pointing it to the wrong location or there is nothing under `locations`, try the code I posted now, is locations under root node? @Mike

Comment: Yes, locations is under the root node. The code you posted looks like what I originally had. I tried to copy and paste what you wrote and still nothing from the loop.

Comment: So I tried getting rid of .child("locations") and just had mFirebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ... }, and it entered the loop and printed: HERE:: DataSnapshot { key = "locations", value = {"2"={"longitude"=-83.018269, "latitude"=39.99941, "descript.... (not sure if that helps narrow the problem)

Comment: Yep, only one "locations". I am not sure what the issue could be. Hm

Comment: Hey Peter, I am also getting this before the loop: /Before Loop:: DataSnapshot { key = null, value = {"locations"={"2"={"longitude"=-83.018269, "latitude"=....  (It is saying that the key is null and the value points to the locations, could that be an issue as well?)

Comment: Share the whole code in the question, only one activity right? No thats not an issue since you are querying on the root above @Mike

Comment: I edited the question to show the entire code for that activity. I have more than one activity, but I am just trying to get it working for this activity at the moment.

Comment: did you recently add 'getValue()' in the log?

Comment: Yeah I just added that. Just trying to see what gets returned

Comment: @Mike change `1` and `2` into a random id using push() and use onchildeventlistener, it should work then

Comment: Hey Peter I just got it to work. I changed the line, mFirebase.child("locations").addValueEventListener to mFirebase.child("\"locations\"").addValueEventListener. Including the quotations to get the child fixes the issue. Is that normal?

Comment: I think you are entering the values from the app and then retrieving, but when u are querying on child("locations"), there are no values there yet

Comment: It looks like you're storing some keys in quotation marks, so a string value `"locations"` (including the quotation marks). Since you have them in your stored data, you'll need to include those quotation marks when reading it too.